# Cap the value of each column depending on a cap value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie to Python. I am working with Python 3.6.

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1.5, 2,1.5,0.8], [1.2, 2,1.5,3], [2, 2,1.5,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Floor', 'V1','V2','V3'])
df
```

Essentially, for each row, if the value in the column `V1` is lower than the value of `Floor`, then I want to set the value of `V1`  equal to `Floor` .

The operation needs to be expanded for each row and for each column (i.e. from column `V1`  to column `V3` where for each row there is the same `Floor` ).

The result would be the following in this example:

```
data = [[1.5, 2,1.5,1.5], [1.2, 2,1.5,3], [2, 2,2,2]]
```

Any idea how to achieve this? I was looking at the function  `where`  but I am not sure how to deploy it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `clip`:

```
df = df.clip(lower=df['Floor'], axis=0)
```

output:

```
>>> df
      Floor  V1        V2        V3
0    1.5000   2    1.5000    1.5000
1    1.2000   2    1.5000    3.0000
2    2.0000   2    2.0000    2.0000
```

###### if you have other columns

```
cols = df.filter(regex='V\d+').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].clip(lower=df['Floor'], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using numpy's `np.where()`. This allows to compare and update a column base on an if/else criteria. Kindly try:

```
df['V1'] = np.where(df['V1'] < df['Floor'],df['Floor'],df['V1']
```

Followed by the same for `V2` and `V3`.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df.update( df.mask(df.loc[:, 'V1':'V3'].lt(df['Floor'], axis=0), df['Floor'], axis=0))
print (df)
   Floor  V1   V2   V3
0    1.5   2  1.5  1.5
1    1.2   2  1.5  3.0
2    2.0   2  2.0  2.0
```